# Punctuations with relative pronouns

Tags: punctuation

Sogou is a Chinese search engine, which can search text, images, music and maps.

Is a comma required before "which" in the above sentence?

Answer (score 5):

With and without the comma are both grammatical, but have different meanings.

Without the comma it is a *defining* (or *restrictive*) relative clause, which narrows the definition. The sentence means something like:

> Sogou is a Chinese search engine, and is capable of searching text, images, and maps (as opposed to some other search engines).

With the comma it is a *commenting* (or *non-restrictive*), which does not affect the definition, but gives some additional information. The sentence with the comma means something like:

> Sogou is a Chinese search engine. Incidentally, it can search text, images and maps (but I'm not saying anything about whether other search engines can do so: maybe they can, maybe they can't. I'm not distinguishing this one, just commenting that it can).

Answer (score 1):

No, in this case "which" begins a defining relative clause (conveys important additional information about the search engine), that's why a comma is not needed here. You can substitute "which" with "that", which you can't do in non-defining relative clauses.

Comment: How do you know it's intended as a defining clause?

Comment: I feel that this additional information is the focus here, not just the fact that Sogou is a search engine. Yes, theoretically there could be a non-defining clause, but it doesn't feel like that at all.

Comment: But since the questioner is actually asking whether the comma is required, it would seem appropriate to confirm what he is trying to say rather than jump to conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the previous answers and would say that you have not provided enough information for us to answer the question definitively.

It is not clear whether you intend it as a *defining clause* or as a *descriptive clause*.

**Defining clause**

In this instance, you want to convey that the fact that it can "search text, images, music and maps" is an *important distinction* between this search engine and other search engines. That piece of information is *critical* to want you are saying. If that is your intent, then I largely agree with the answer from @Vilmar but would go further:

- The comma is not merely "not needed", *it should be omitted*. Including the comma changes the meaning.
- Yes, you can use "that" instead of "which", and that would make the intention clear.

So, if your intention is a *defining* clause, use:

> Sogou is a Chinese search engine which can search text, images, music and maps.
>   Sogou is a Chinese search engine that can search text, images, music and maps.

**Describing clause**

On the other hand, if your main point is that "Sogou is a Chinese search engine" and the additional information that it can "search text, images, music and maps" is optional & incidental to mentioning the search engine's name, then you want a *descriptive* clause, and the comma *is required*:

> Sogou is a Chinese search engine, which can search text, images, music and maps.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to use a comma, you could rephrase as:

Sogou is a Chinese search engine, capable of searching text, images, music and maps.

Comment: This isn't an answer to OP's question, and (worse in my opinion) adds complication rather than clarity.